# value is not getting in sharedpreferences, always default value is coming

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am storing one value in sharedpreferences using the below code

```
                 SharedPreferences sp;
       sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myshare",
                                 MODE_PRIVATE);
                 Editor e = sp.edit();
                 e.putString("a","unni");
                 e.commit();
```

this is in AddBluetooth Activity

Now I am retrieving that value from another  activity called Dashboard Activity, which is using the below code

```
  SharedPreferences sp;
  sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myshare",
                 MODE_PRIVATE);
  String aa =sp.getString("a","me");
```

but its's only returning the default value, how can I fix this issue

Comment: try out the syntax i have posted as answer..use SharedPreferences.Editor editor; instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually for me the above code snippet is not working in API 19, but for lower versions its working. So I used,

```
 SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor=saved_values.edit();
                 editor.putString("newCEAAddress", address);    
                 editor.commit();
```

for getting value

```
  SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    DEVICE_ADDRESS=saved_values.getString("newCEAAddress", "nil");
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you're defining your preferences in a preferences.xml you need to access it using `SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`

Answer (score 0):

```
  // declare this class variable in class from where u will put the string u wanna store in shared pref 

    //class variables

        SharedPreferences pref;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    -------------------

    //in oncrete method
    // declare this in oncreate method 

            pref = getSharedPreferences("testapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = pref.edit();

    // the varibale u wanna put use the below statements 
    // for string use putString
    // for boolean as u need use putBoolean 
    // have a look at the various option it offers..


    editor.putString("selected", "nil");
    editor.commit();


    // here is the statement use this statement in class where u wanna retireve ur strings
    // use getBoolean for Boolean variables 

    pref.getString("selected", "nil")

    // here in sceond parameter in above statement is : if the value u r requesting for that is specified in first parameter is not present then it will return the //value which is your second parameter..
```

Pull Ur Shared-Pref :
Go to Data-->Data-->Ur package-->Pull The SharedPref file [DDMS]